# Change string variable from function in imported module

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, speech-recognition

I am making a python Tkinter GUI that will transcribe audio from microphone to text in real time and at the same time, show a warning message on screen if the word "oh no" or "erm" is spoken and detected. I imported the speech recognition script `transcribe.py` as a module into the main program `sample.py`. My question is: How can I change the text of the tk.Label in my main program `sample.py` when the word "erm" is detected in the imported module`transcribe.py`?

Below is my code.

```
#sample.py(class of the window that the warning message should be shown on)

import transcribe.py

class PracticePage(tk.Frame, App):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Frame.config(self, bg="white")

        global label_var 
        label_var = tk.StringVar()
        label_var.set("")
        self.timeLeft = tk.Label(self, textvariable= label_var, font ="遊ゴジックLight 20", bg ="white")

        self.timeLeft.place(relwidth = 0.4, relheight = 0.1, relx = 0.5, rely = 0.45, anchor = "center")
```

and this is part of the code in my speech recognition module.

```
#transcribe.py
def listen_print_loop(responses): #responses is the audio stream from microphone
spoken = []

for response in responses:
    if not response.results:
        continue

    result = response.results[0]
    if not result.alternatives:
        continue

    transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    overwrite_chars = ' ' * (num_chars_printed - len(transcript))

    spoken.append(transcript + overwrite_chars)

    if "erm" in spoken:
        #change the text of label in sample.py here

    if not result.is_final:
        num_chars_printed = len(transcript)

    else:
        spoken.append(transcript + overwrite_chars)
        final_spoken = ''.join(spoken) 
        print(final_spoken)
```

I am a python beginner and sorry if my question is confusing. Please ask me further if you don't understand anything. Thank you.

Comment: make use of .labelText = 'change the value'

Comment: sorry I still don't understand what you meant. Did you mean writing self.labelText = "change the value" in sample.py?

Comment: where have you used instance of PracticePage ?

Comment: i created the instance in sample.py

Comment: can you add that code as well?

Comment: Change to `self.label_var` and then `<PracticePage Instance>.label_var.set(...`.